# copy const char* to string in c

Tags: c, string, char, constants

In C [not C++]:

How can I copy a `const char*` into a string (char array)?

I have:

```
const char *d="/home/aemara/move/folder"
char tar[80] ;
int dl=strlen(d);
int x=0;
while (x<dl){tar[x]=d[x]; x++; }
printf("tar[80]: %s\n",tar);
```

Prints out: `tar[80]: /home/aemara/move/folderøèB`
The problem is that this way, adds garbage at the end of the array [sometimes, not always]
How can I fix it ? or there is another way to copy `const char*` into a string ?

Comment: @GregHewgill he probably wants to learn how to copy two strings. Probably homework

Comment: @PrototypeStark: I certainly understand the idea of exercises for learning, but if that were the case then why would strlen() be permitted? Also, I don't assume random restrictions unless explicitly specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you should do:

```
const char *d="/home/aemara/move/folder";//Semi-colon was missing in your posted code
char tar[80];
memset(tar,0x00,80);//This always a best practice to memset any array before use
int dl=strlen(d);//This returns length of the string in excluding the '\0' in the string
int x=0;
if(dl<79)// Check for possible overflow, 79th byte reserved=1 byte for '\0'
while (x<dl){ tar[x]=d[x]; x++; }
if(x<80) d[x]=0;//If not using memset have to use this, xth byte initialized to '\0'
printf("\ntar[80]: %s\n",tar);
```

Comment: "This always a best practice to memset any array before use". No it's not. That is defensive programming and may simply mask other logic errors. While there are some cases where clearing the array as the first step is appropriate, in most cases it should be unnecessary.

Comment: The comment was w.r.to the OP's question and context. And I do agree, with your comments, too.

Answer (score 3):

`strlen` returns the length without the null terminator. You need to copy one more byte.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add a '\0' character at the end after copying.

To solve this, `memset(tar,'\0',80);`

Or :

```
if(d1 < 80){ //bad idea, don't use magic numbers
  while(x < d1){ tar[x] = d[x]; x++;}
  tar[x] = '\0';
}
printf..
```

Answer (score 1):

`strlen`'s return value doesn't include the NULL terminator.

Add the following line after the `while` loop

```
tar[dl] = '\0';
```

Or you could zero initialize `tar` when you declare the array.

```
char tar[80] = {0};
```

Now you don't need to NULL terminate after the loop.